# Arduino stops my code if I put LCD loop codes

Tags: loops, arduino, arduino-uno, lcd

I'm little bit new to Arduino and English is not my first lang so there can be some errors.

I'm just doing a project as a hobby to keep the time going. I'm trying to get air temperature, water temperature and water flow rate. For these datas I'm using

LM35DZ, DS18B20, YF-S201

and they are working great although I got some codes from another projects. I'm getting those datas from serial monitor and I got a LCD to see those datas.

After I put the LCD codes, void setup part is working great. I'm getting the A: H: S: / where they should be (You will understand what I'm talking about when you look to the LCD part of my code on the setup). For the loop part, it's not working when I put the lcd codes at the end and on the serial monitor it stops when it's calculating water flow (Serial monitor works well if I delete those codes).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU9EY.jpg

I put my whole code incase you need it to see. You can just skip to the problem.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 4
DeviceAddress thermometerAddress;
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature tempSensor(&oneWire);

//havasicaklik
int lm35Pin = A0;
int okunan_deger = 0;
float sicaklik_gerilim = 0;
float sicaklik = 0;
float susicakligi = 0;

//suakis
volatile int NbTopsFan; //measuring the rising edges of the signal
int Calc;                              
#define hallsensor 2    //The pin location of the sensor

//potansiyometre
#define pts A1
float ptsck = 30;

//lcd
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void rpm () {    //This is the function that the interupt calls
NbTopsFan++;  //This function measures the rising and falling edge of the
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //susicaklik
  tempSensor.begin();
  tempSensor.setResolution(thermometerAddress, 9);

  //suakis
  pinMode(hallsensor, INPUT); //initializes digital pin 2 as an input
  attachInterrupt(0, rpm, RISING); //and the interrupt is attached

  //lcd
  lcd.begin();
  //yükleme ekranı
  lcd.home();
  lcd.print(" Berke  Karasah");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Yukleniyor"); //This is just to make it look like it's loading
  for (int k = 0;k < 2; k++) {
    for (int i = 0;i < 7; i++) {
    delay(75);
    lcd.print(".");
    }
  lcd.setCursor(10,1);
  lcd.print("      ");
  lcd.setCursor(10,1);
  }
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.home();        // This part where the datas should be*******
  lcd.print("A: ");     //Calc: Water flow
  lcd.setCursor(7,0);
  lcd.print("H:");     //sicaklik: Air temp
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("S: ");    //susicakligi: Water temp
  lcd.setCursor(9,1);
  lcd.print("/");      //ptsck: Potentiometer value
}

void loop() {

  delay(1000);

  //havasicaklik
  okunan_deger = analogRead(lm35Pin);
  sicaklik_gerilim = (5000.0 / 1023.0) * okunan_deger;
  sicaklik = sicaklik_gerilim / 10.0;
  Serial.print("Hava sicakligi: ");
  Serial.print(sicaklik);

  Serial.print("\t");

  //susicaklik
  tempSensor.requestTemperatures();
  Serial.print("Su sicakligi: ");
  susicakligi = tempSensor.getTempCByIndex(0);
  Serial.print(susicakligi);

  Serial.print("\t");

  //potansiyometre
  ptsck = analogRead(pts);
  ptsck = map(ptsck, 0,1023,0,50);
  Serial.print("Hedef sicaklik: ");
  Serial.print(ptsck);

  Serial.print("\t");

  //suakis
  NbTopsFan = 0;    //Set NbTops to 0 ready for calculations
  sei();            //Enables interrupts
  delay(1000);      //Wait 1 second
  cli();            //Disable interrupts
  Calc = (NbTopsFan * 60 / 7.5); //(Pulse frequency x 60) / 7.5Q, = flow rate
  Serial.print("Akis hizi: ");
  Serial.print(Calc, DEC); //Prints the number calculated above
  Serial.print(" L/s"); //Prints "L/hour" and returns a  new line

  Serial.print("\n");

  //lcd        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!THIS IS THE PROBLEM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  lcd.setCursor(3,0);
  lcd.print(Calc);
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
  lcd.print(sicaklik);
  lcd.setCursor(3,1);
  lcd.print(susicakligi);
  lcd.setCursor(11,1);
  lcd.print(ptsck);


}
```

Comment: You can find the solution for the problem [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=421005.msg2899243#msg2899243)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an `lcd.clear()` before the following;

```
  lcd.setCursor(3,0);
  lcd.print(Calc);
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
  lcd.print(sicaklik);
  lcd.setCursor(3,1);
  lcd.print(susicakligi);
  lcd.setCursor(11,1);
  lcd.print(ptsck);
```

and a `delay(100);` after.

Comment: Nothing changed. It's still stuck like in the screenshot. Btw I don't want to clear my lcd, I want to put the values to the blank parts of the LCD. You can see it in the photo as well.